# USB not recognized by computer

Tags: usb, fft, stm32

I am using stm32 device which connected to another MCU by SWO.
When I am uploading code base on FFT (heavy code i suppose), the MCU not connecting to my PC.
Why it is happening? and how can I solve it?

I didnt upload the code, because the code is OK, maybe something in the configuration or how the USB work.
But this is part of the code, who make me troubles:

```
arm_cfft_radix4_init_f32(&S, FFT_SIZE, 0, 1);
arm_cfft_radix4_f32(&S, input);
arm_cmplx_mag_f32(input, AFFT, FFT_SIZE);
arm_max_f32(AFFT, FFT_SIZE, &maxValue, &maxIndex);
```

I will be grateful if you can help me, or give me a lead.
Thank you very much.

Edit:
I have notice that the RO-data swelled from 680 to 35,304 bytes:

[RO-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6G04.png)

There is any connection between RO-data, and not response from USB?

Comment: sorry but your post doesn't make any sense to me. how are 4 lines of FFT code realted to USB? you say the code is working but yet you post it because it troubles you?  are there any error messages? what STM32 device are you talking about? how do you implement USB? this cannot be answered as is. please improve your post

Comment: The code is more than 4 lines, but when I am adding those lines I have problem with the connectivity of the device (STM32L476rg).
There isnt any errors or warnings.
The implement of the USB is auto by cubeMX.

I will explain myself again.
I have MCU device.
I write code for him, and it work perfectly.
I added those 4 line, and after compile and uploading the code for the STM device, the computer are not recognize the device. I dont know why =/

Comment: Your questions mentions two MCUs, a SWO connection, a USB connection to PC etc. Can you somehow isolate the problem and come up with a simpler setup that exhibits the same problem, e.g. just a single MCU and the USB connection? If not, can you better describe the setup, i.e. which MCU is connected to USB, which MCU runs the FFT code etc.? Or are you describing a Nucleo board with a second MCU on-board that acts as an ST-Link? If so, are you saying that the computer no longer detects the ST-Link connected via USB?

Comment: Hi Codo, thank you for your patience.
I draw scheme to explain my situation:
https://prnt.sc/uqk08z

Comment: The code most likely crashes the MCU. So it's stuck in an error handler and doesn't respond on the USB communication anymore. The computer will consider it dead. So it looks as if the computer does not recognize it. Use a debugger to check where the code is stuck, and what caused it to crash. Another possibility is that the code takes too long to execute and delays the USB code. It will also appear as dead.

Comment: Hi again, why the code crashing the MCU? what make it?
The code crash at this command: arm_cfft_radix4_f32(&S, input);

This is part of a FFT algorithm (complicate function). debugger shot me HardFault_Handler error

Comment: I noticed now, the USB connecting to the computer after 20 second +-, but the computer not recognize it. maybe the problem is the second option you gave